# Chrome reports HTTP 400 for CSS background-image combined with gradient

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-gradients

I have some CSS like this:

```
background: url(evil-whales.png),
linear-gradient(to bottom,
#4e4e4e 81%,
rgba(77,140,70,0.7) 82%,
rgba(76,201,61,0) 83%,
rgba(78,78,78,0) 100%
);
```

Firefox reports everything is dandy though Chrome reports an HTTP 400.

> evil-whales.png,%20linear-gradient(rgb(78,%2078,%2078)%2081%,%20rg…%20rgba(76,%20201,%2061,%200)%2083%,%20rgba(78,%2078,%2078,%200)%20100%):1
>   GET ...

How do I resolve this without simply hiding it from the console view?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try surrounding the URL in quotes?

Comment: @Quantastical Yes, no difference.

Comment: Seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/how2wyks/ - does not report any 400 errors.
Is your CSS inline or in a separate file?

Comment: @HaukurHaf I've got Chrome 49.0.2623.75 m. Not a lot of information on CSS multiple background-images with gradients though it *does* work even though the request is goofy. I think it's sending the gradient as an HTTP query perhaps?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what it's doing.  It's url encoding the linear gradient as if it's being sent as a HTTP request.